# Nuget package Version Issue for YAML

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, nuget, azure-pipelines

I am trying to get the Nuget file generated in the drop folder to have a name like this - Project.1.0.1-prerelease-2021-05-10.nupkg. But the output of this YAML in the build pipeline is Project.0.1.0.nupkg. What is not correct here? I have tried too many combinations but it keeps generating this in the drop folder.

[image]

The csproj file does have a version prefix field like this though

[image]

YAML

```
# ASP.NET Core
# Build and test ASP.NET Core projects targeting .NET Core.
# Add steps that run tests, create a NuGet package, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/dotnet-core

name: $(BuildDefinitionName)_$(Year:yyyy).$(Month).$(DayOfMonth)$(Rev:.r)

trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Restore Dependencies'
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    vstsFeed: '9fc2d633-cc8b-49be-a58d-abb9adf6a2c9'
    
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Debug Build'
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    configuration: debug
    
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Pack Pre Release'
  inputs:
    command: 'pack'
    packagesToPack: '**/Project.csproj'
    includesymbols: true
    includesource: true
    packDirectory: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/release'
    arguments: '--configuration debug'
    versioningScheme: byPrereleaseNumber
    majorVersion: 1
    minorVersion: 0
    patchVersion: 1
    
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Artifacts'
  inputs:
    Contents: '**\*.nupkg'
    TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish artifacts'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so got it working by changing this

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Pack Pre Release'
  inputs:
    command: 'pack'
    packagesToPack: '**/Project.csproj'
    includesymbols: true
    includesource: true
    packDirectory: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/release'
    arguments: '--configuration debug'
    versioningScheme: byPrereleaseNumber
    majorVersion: 1
    minorVersion: 0
    patchVersion: 1
```

to this

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Pack pre-release package'
  inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    projects: '**/Project.csproj'
    custom: 'pack'
    arguments: '--version-suffix "pre-release-"$(Build.BuildNumber) --output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/debug'
```

And also right at the top, I changed the name variable to

```
name: $(Year:yyyy).$(Month).$(DayOfMonth)$(Rev:.r)
```

And that gives me this package.

[image]

Comment: Great! You could accept this answer. This will be helpful to other users.